# Spring MVC 3 servlet.xml .. what is the use of the initial lines?

Tags: spring-mvc

In Spring MVC 3, what is the purpose of defining these lines

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
```

in the `<servletName>-servlet.xml` file.

Answer (score 2):

Those are [XML Schemas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29). [The Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html) does quite a good job describing the schemas mentioned.